# display content of html file in php

Tags: php, file, file-upload

Hi guys I want to create simple file system using php. I want to display content of uploaded file using php. But whene I upload html or php file then instead of showing its content, html or php code gets executed. I want to display that files without executing. Plz help me. Thank you.

Comment: In general, `echo htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents('filename'))`. But show us your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If PHP get's executed you are including/requiring the file. Read it's contents instead, e.g. with [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)
To prevent the browser from parsing the HTML use [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Example:

```
<?php
$filename = "test.html";
echo "<pre><code>";
echo htmlentities(file_get_contents($filename));
echo "</code></pre>";
?>
```

Comment: Thanx...Worked perfectly..But sorry I cannot vote your Answer because my reputation in low.

Comment: @jagdish You can accept the Answer as soon as the time limit is up though

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the raw code, you can:

a) Make it a text file

or

b) use htmlentities() on the output

Answer (score 0):

Shows the content of the file:

```
readfile($yourFilename);
```

If you don't want the browser to interpret your code, try  and setting "wrong" MIME types.