# CK editor data displaying with html tags in php

Tags: html, ckeditor, editor

CK editor data displaying with html tags in php
please help me...

```html
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header text-uppercase">Product Description</div>
<?php echo $result['description'];?>

</div>
</div>
 </div>
```

[it's displaying like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMqEN.png)

[but should displaying like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8sk4.png)

Comment: Try this solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384065/display-content-of-html-file-in-php

Comment: thank you for your concern but I did not asked for this...please see may attached images

Comment: I watched your images and i assumed from them maybe you were looking for something that i mentioned earlier. No worries

Answer (score 0):

Please use this "html_entity_decode"

Example:
`$str = '&lt;a href=&quot;https://www.w3schools.com&quot;&gt;w3schools.com&lt;/a&gt;'; echo html_entity_decode($str);`